# how to find derivative of an equation of matrices with element-wise multiplication or division

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

For an equation like this:

$$ M= \left(\begin{array}{c} A\:x-B \otimes y\end{array}\right) \oslash C $$

where $\otimes$ is a Hadamard element-wise multiplication and $\oslash$ is a Hadamard element-wise division.

A, B and C are real matrices with (n×m), (n×k) and (n×k), respectively.

Whereas, x and y are vectors with (m×1) and (n×1), respectively.

**I need to find the derivative of $M$ with respect to the vector $x$**

Note that symbols $\otimes$ and $\oslash$ represents the Hadamard product and division which are built into certain programming languages under various names. Sometimes its called broadcast multiplication or array multiplication. [See reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#In_programming_languages)

Here is a simple pseudo code in MATLAB to illustrate array multiplication (broadcast multiplication).

```
n = 4;
m = 3;
k = 2;

A = sym('A', [n m]);
B = sym('B', [n k]);
C = sym('C', [n k]);

x = sym('x', [m 1]);
y = sym('y', [n 1]);

M = (A*x-B.*y)./C
```

**The question is, what is the derivative of $M$ with respect to the vector $x$**

Answer (score 1):

Modern computer matrix languages (*Matlab, Julia, etc*) do indeed use broadcasting when asked to perform element-wise multiplication on matrices whose sizes are incompatible, but I think that long-term exposure to such languages has dulled your math instincts because $\ldots$

$\ldots$ your equation does not make any sense mathematically. Here is a modified equation with the broadcasting operations shown *explicitly:*
$$\eqalign{
{\tt1_k} &\in{\mathbb R}^{k\times 1} \quad&\big({\rm all\,ones\,vector}\big) \\
C\otimes D = {\tt 1_{nk}}
  &\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times k} \;&\big({\rm all\,ones\,matrix}\big) \\
M &= \big(Ax{\tt1_k}^T\;+&B\otimes y{\tt1_k}^T\big)\otimes D
}$$
The advantage of using the matrix $D$ instead of $C$ is that operands of a Hadamard product **commute**, while those of Hadamard division do not.

To proceed, calculate the SVD of $A$ and substitute it into the definition of $M$.
$$\eqalign{
A &= \sum_{i=1}^{\rm rank(A)} \sigma_i u_iv_i^T \\
M &= \big(D\otimes B\otimes y{\tt1_k}^T\big)
   + D\otimes\sum_{i=1}^{\rm rank(A)} \sigma_iu_i \color{red}{v_i^Tx}{\tt1_k}^T \\
  &= E + \sum_{i=1}^{\rm rank(A)}\Big(D\otimes \sigma_iu_i{\tt1_k}^T\Big)
         \star(v_i^Tx) \\
  &= E + \sum_{i=1}^{\rm rank(A)}\big(F_i\big)\star(v_i^Tx) \\
}$$
Then calculate the differential, and then the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
dM &= \sum_{i=1}^{\rm rank(A)}\big(F_i\big)\star(v_i^Tdx) \\
\Gamma = \frac{\partial M}{\partial x}
 &= \sum_{i=1}^{\rm rank(A)} F_i\star v_i^T \\
}$$
The $\star$ denotes a tensor/dyadic product, and this gradient is a third-order tensor whose $(p,q,r)^{th}$ component is found by contracting with the $(p^{th},q^{th},r^{th})$ vectors from the standard basis. 
$$\eqalign{
&e_p \in {\mathbb R}^{n\times 1} \qquad
e_q \in {\mathbb R}^{k\times 1} \qquad
e_r \in {\mathbb R}^{m\times 1} \\
&\Gamma_{pqr}=\frac{\partial M_{pq}}{\partial x_r}
  = \sum_{i=1}^{\rm rank(A)} (e_p^TF_ie_q)\star(v_i^Te_r) \\
\\
}$$
Another way to handle this gradient is to vectorize the matrices (by column-stacking)
$$\eqalign{
m &= {\rm vec}(M),\quad f_i &= {\rm vec}(F_i) \\
}$$
Now you can write the differential as a vector, and the gradient as an ordinary matrix.
$$\eqalign{
dm &= \sum_{i=1}^{\rm rank(A)} f_i v_i^Tdx \\
G = \frac{\partial m}{\partial x} &= \sum_{i=1}^{\rm rank(A)} f_i v_i^T \\
G_{sr} = \frac{\partial m_s}{\partial x_r}
 &= \sum_{i=1}^{\rm rank(A)} e_s^T\big(f_iv_i^T\big)e_r\qquad
 \Big(m,f_i,e_s\in{\mathbb R}^{nk\times 1}\Big) \\
}$$
But I wonder why you are interested in this gradient. My guess is that you actually have no interest whatsoever. Rather you *think* you need it because it appears as an intermediate quantity when the chain rule is applied to a larger problem. If so, please be aware that there are simpler ways to approach such problems which do not require *any* third or fourth order tensor calculations.

#### Update

It occurred to me that the above gradients can be written in a form which doesn't require the calculation of the SVD of $A$: 
$$\eqalign{
G &= \Big(\big(D^T\boxtimes{\tt1_n}\big)
\otimes \big({\tt1_k}\boxtimes {\tt I_n}\big)\Big) A \\
\Gamma_{pqr} &= \big(e_p\otimes De_q\big)^T Ae_r \\
}$$
where ${\tt I_n}\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$ is the identity matrix and $\boxtimes$ denotes the Kronecker product, because we've previously used the symbol $\otimes$ to represent the Hadamard product.

Comment: Thank you greg for your great and detailed clarification.    You guessed right, in my case, I need a much much simpler analysis than third or fourth order tensor calculations. I am building a nonlinear optimization problem and the provided $M$ equation is a simplified form of an equation I'm developing. I am trying to find its derivative w.r.t $x$ to investigate its KKT conditions (Optimality conditions)